# Image compositing

Tags: python, image, composite, cairo

I have an album title of some music band. I want to draw it with some mask which will round the corners of image.
So, I've prepared such mask in gimp:

[image]

I'm using white mask, but it's invisible at white background here.
So, here is the code of rendering:

```
# Draw album image
img = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png('images/album.png')
ctx.set_source_surface(img, posX, posY)
ctx.paint()

# Draw mask
ctx.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_DEST_IN)
img = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png('images/mask.png')
ctx.set_source_surface(img, posX, posY)
ctx.paint()
```

As you see, I've used `OPERATOR_DEST_IN`. Quick examples I found at [this page](http://cairographics.org/operators/).

But, everything disappeared in my program when I set compositing operator in cairo :(. When I comment that line everything is okay, but mask is over my image. What is the right way for that?

p.s. I'm using python2, cairo library

---

When I remove compositing operator I see (don't forget that real mask is white, in this case album image is dark):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to share your surface creation code as well, here's some code I extended from your example:

```
import cairo

surface = cairo.ImageSurface (cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 128, 128)
ctx = cairo.Context (surface)

posX = posY = 0

img = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png('sample.png')  
ctx.set_source_surface(img, posX, posY)  
ctx.paint()

# Draw mask
ctx.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_DEST_IN)
img = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png('mask.png')
ctx.set_source_surface(img, posX, posY)
ctx.paint()

surface.write_to_png ("example.png") # Output to PNG
```

Which generated this beautiful png below (it was the only image on my desktop at the moment ;)[image]

Comment: np ;) I'm guessing your surface wasn't ARGB.